# Is there anyway to embed image in <Text> in react-native

Tags: react-native

Someone may want to implement a richtext edit or richtext view.
    In html we can do it with inline image tag, but react-native Text can only nest Text in it.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a workaround that'll preserve styles

```
<View style={{flexDirection:'row', flexWrap:'wrap'}}>
    <Image
        style={styles.img}
        source={{uri: imageLink}} />
    <Text>
        {"sweet, this works"}
    </Text>
</View>
```

Comment: doesn't suite well for multiline texts

Comment: u can not do it when u didnt know the number of images

Answer (score 3):

This was already added to React Native back in 0.16-rc. Update your React Native version and see examples here:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/a0268a7bfc8000b5297d2b50f81e000d1f479c76

Comment: Thanks. It's what I want. But I tried it, it's only working on ios now and the style seems not working. specifying width and height of the image in text doesnot work.

Comment: I found I was able to nest Image within Text, but I wasn't able to then control the margins of the image to provide some separation between the image and the text. Ended up using the flex solution posted by @Ricky.