# Show mix image from url and text in one view react-native

Tags: react-native

I have a problem and don't know how to fix it. I have a message like this:

***This is my message:tongue_out::wink:dsdangrydsangryhoanghamobile.comdsd:wink:this is emoji and more text....***

It's will be show like an image below with *:wink: , :tongue_out:*  and the others emoji is an image from link: https://filev4.subiz.com/wink.png. All is an string and now i have to parse emoji from url and text to display. I don't know how many text and emoji contain, and how to display all in one view in react-native. Now, i really need some help, thank very much.

[image]

Comment: No one know that?

Comment: you could try this and let me know https://github.com/makemoji/Makemoji-React-Native

Comment: @Asifvora thank for suggestion, I try and get error **Cannot read property 'func' of undefined.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Slice the message to **TEMP** array, like this `['This is my message',':tongue_out:',':wink:']`
2. With **TEMP**, detect element `:abc:` for image, then you can loop and display `Text` and `Image` inline, like [inline-image](https://medium.com/@yloeza/react-native-text-inline-image-6055dabd9399) or [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532552/is-there-anyway-to-embed-image-in-text-in-react-native)
3. The Emoji is the remote image so you have to cache it for fast display. You can use [FastImage](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image)

Comment: Chuyển từ text thành array phải dùng split chứ nhỉ, hiện tại mình đã dùng split nhưng phát sinh 1 vấn đề đó là ngay khi đoạn text đó không phải emoji thì nó làm mất luôn dấu **:**.

Comment: This is the way to solve my problem: `const arrayComponent = text.match(/:\w+:|.+?(?=:\w+:|$)/g);`

Comment: 'Split' is more correct. I think using regex is a good choice (y). Good luck, have fun.