# How to use split without change text content

Tags: javascript

I have a text like this:

```
let text = ":wink: Is that true? :like: I never heard about that, as I know some country like: VN, Indonesia, ThaiLan".
```

**:wink:** and **:like:** is code to display emoji. Now i use split to covert into array like this:

```
const myArray = text.split(':')
```

and result:

```
myArray = ["", "wink", " Is that true? ", "like", " I never heard about that, as I know some country like", " VN, Indonesia, ThaiLan"]
```

as you can see, character '**:**' is gone, how to keep ':' when covert from text to array, in this case my expect the result should be:

```
myArray = [":wink:", " Is that true? ", ":like:", " I never heard about that, as I know some country like:", " VN, Indonesia, ThaiLan"]
```

Comment: Is that array really your goal, or is your goal to replace `:wink:` and `:like:` with emojis? (Building that array probably isn't the right way to do the latter.)

Comment: Do you want to split off the `VN, Indonesia, ThaiLan` at the end?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51378198/show-mix-image-from-url-and-text-in-one-view-react-native This is my main question :D

Answer (score 1):

Try using `match` instead: match colons followed by non-colons followed by a final colon, OR match anything up until a point that's followed by `:word:`:

```js
let text = ":wink: Is that true? :like: I never heard about that, as I know some country like: VN, Indonesia, ThaiLan";
console.log(text.match(
  /:\w+:|.+?(?=:\w+:|$)/g
));
```

Comment: This removes the colon from `country like:`, which may not be OK.

Comment: If text like this: **:tongue-out:sdasd:unlike:dsad:sleepy:dad** result is: **[":tongue-out", ":sdasd:", "unlike", ":dsad:", "sleepy:dad"]** and it's not display emoji.