# React Native: text wrap doesn't wrap when embedding components

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to embed custom components (clickable tags) inline into a text block. However, I am having issues with the flex-wrap where it does not split up individual text blocks but instead puts them on a new line. I'm already implementing solutions found in [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532552/is-there-anyway-to-embed-image-in-text-in-react-native). Does anyone have pointers on where I am going wrong? Here is the code block (added background color for ease and used stub text values):

```js
return (
        <View style={styles().container}>
                {textParts.map((part, i) => {
                    if (i % 2 === 0) {
                        return <Text style={styles().nonAnchorText} key={i}>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</Text>
                    } else {
                        return <Text style={styles().anchorText} key={i}>TAG</Text>
                    }
                })}
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = () => StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flexDirection: "row",
        flexWrap: "wrap",
        backgroundColor: "grey",
},
    nonAnchorText: {
        backgroundColor: "beige",
        fontSize: 17,
        flexWrap: "wrap",
    },
    anchorText: {
        backgroundColor: "pink",
        fontSize: 17,
        flexWrap: "wrap",
    }
});
```

This is the result when ideally, I'd want the Lorem ipsum blocks split up into multiple lines so that it looks like a normal paragraph
[image: result]

Comment: When I wrap the entire thing in Text, it correctly breaks, however the centering is off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up wrapping the two Text components with an additional Text component instead of a View. (Previously, I had been using touchableOpacity as the anchor component, but that was throwing off the positioning). No flexwrap was needed. Not sure if this is the best solution:

```js
return (
        <Text style={styles().container}>
                {textParts.map((part, i) => {
                    if (i % 2 === 0) {
                        return <Text style={styles().nonAnchorText} key={i}>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</Text>
                    } else {
                        return <Text style={styles().anchorText} key={i}>TAG</Text>
                    }
                })}
        </Text>
    );
}

const styles = () => StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: "grey",
},
    nonAnchorText: {
        backgroundColor: "beige",
        fontSize: 17,
    },
    anchorText: {
        backgroundColor: "pink",
        fontSize: 17,
    }
});
```